# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building my own forum as practice, I set up `Topic` and `Comment` models with polymorphic relationship, a `comment` can belong to a `topic` or another `comment`, this is because I want to have nested comments. Another issue is when I reply to the topic I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`user_id`, `body`, `commentable_id`, `commentable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1 <\p>ljlnlnlnlnlnllnlnlnlnlnln</p>, 1, App\Models\Topic, 2019-11-08 20:41:43, 2019-11-08 20:41:43))

My models and Migrations.

Topic model:

```php
class Topic extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'topics';

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable')->whereNull('parent_id');
    }
}
```

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('url')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->boolean('isVisible')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment model:

```php
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('commentable_type');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty obvious; the column `parent_id` doesn't have a value (you're not setting one, and there is no default). Either set the column as `nullable`, or pass a `parent_id`

In `migration`:

```
$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a comment on a topic has no parent comment (not a reply) then the `parent_id` would be null, however your database schema doesn't allow it, make the column nullable

```php
$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

or give it `null` as the default value

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->default(null);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In the PHP language, the null type is assigned per default to a variable if no value was given in advance. This allows to create complex semantic databases more easily. The problem can be fixed by passing the parent id to the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and solved by adding my column into fillable property

Add parent_id to the fillable array in your model **Comment** , to allow saving through create and massive methods

```
protected $fillable = ['parent_id'];
```